# search for lines which contain a pattern but do not contain a second pattern

Tags: search

I need to search for lines which contain some word but do *not* contain a second word.

For example, find lines that contain the word "This" but not the word "red"

so that for a file containing these lines

```
This is a blue coat
This is a red  coat
This is a purple coat
That is a coat
```

The search would locate the first and third lines only.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You can use the LogiPat plugin that is distributed with newer Vims

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And there is also another way with `:global` command, as follows:

```
:g/This\C/v/red/p
```

and the first `:g` command filter the lines contains `This`, and then passed into the second `:v` command to show lines that don't contain `red`, and at last, `p` (short for `print`) is applied to those lines with matches.

This is the charm of vim.

Comment: Thanks @TroyDaniel, could you explain what the `\C` does please?

Comment: In vim, the `\C` in regex means `case-sensitive`, and `\c` (with lower c) means `case-insensitive`.  For more details, you can `:h \C`.

Comment: Thanks @TroyDaniel, I've been wanting to know how to do case-insensitive searches for decades!      But your suggestion *includes* red, rather than excluding it, thus returning just the second line.       Could you modify your answer please to exclude red?    I tried playing around with the `@` syntax above but couldn't get it to work in your setting

Comment: As long as you know `:g` command, you shold know `:g!` or `:v` command. If not, please do `:h :v`.

Comment: Thus, it's simple to modify the above command as: `:g/This\C/v/red/p`, which acts as you want.

Comment: Note: this needs at least Vim 8.0.630. Using `:g` recursively was disallowed in older versions

Comment: @LeoSimon On the off chance you're not already aware of these, there's also `:help 'ignorecase'` and `:help 'smartcase'`, if you want to use case-insensitive searches on a more permanent basis.

Answer (score 30):

You can use this command to print lines containing `This` and not `red`:

```
:g/\(.*This\)\&\(.*red\)\@!
```

- `\&` separates the branches like a logical `AND` because we want the lines that satisfy the two conditions (branches),
- `\(.*This\)` is the first branch, it could simply be `This` but it is more generic that way,
- `\(.*red\)\@!` is the second branch, `\@!` means "zero width match if the preceding atom doesn't match", like a logical `NOT`.

In other words:

```
\(.*This\)  \&  \(.*red\)\@!
°°°°°°°°°°  °°  °°°°°°°°°°°°
'This'      AND NOT 'red'
```

Comment: Much thanks, this is very much like a query through formatted text. I was able to use this to find functions missing docstrings.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this post.

Combine it with @romainl answer and you can do whatever you want.

Example:
Let's say I want to add a `const` to the functions which doesn't have them.

```
    handleChange = value => {
```

VIM script:

```
%s/\([ ]*\)\(\w* = .*$\)\&^\(\&\(.*const.*\)\@!.\)*$/\1const \2/gc
```

Output:

```
    const handleChange = value => {
```

Explanation:

```
\([ ]*\)\(\w* = .*$\)
```

- get me all lines which has `word =`

```
\&
```

- combine rules

```
^\(\&\(.*const.*\)\@!.\)*$
```

- the line shouldn't contain `const`.